# How do you download a list of 300 files from a server (Anonfiles specifically)

Tags: download, operating-systems, file-transfer, links

I have a huge list of files, more than 300 but I was giving an estimate.

I have them like this:

https://anonfiles.com/1.mp4
https://anonfiles.com/2.mp4
https://anonfiles.com/3.mp4
https://anonfiles.com/4.mp4
https://anonfiles.com/5.mp4

Is there desktop software that can do this for any OS?

I tried Tabsave and Chronos recommended in another thread, but tabsave just saved 400 HTML files which was not what I needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For any POSIX-compatible system use curl. Usage of curl: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/curl.1.html.
For Windows you can use:

1. WSL for emulating Linux.
2. PowerShell:
   2.1. `For` manual: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_for?view=powershell-7.2
   2.2. How to make requests in PowerShell: https://lazyadmin.nl/powershell/download-file-powershell

---

The algorithm for bash:

```bash
curl "https://anonfiles.com/[1-400].mp4"
```